# Nested class of methods acess outer class __init__

Tags: python, class, oop, inner-classes

I'm trying to create a structure in which I define a set of constants (here, a file and some metadata) which are stored so that I can run methods grouped into subclasses.

Here is my structure:

```
class diagnostics(object):
    # set up some shared attributes which are always constant
    def __init__(self,root_dir, file, year, doy):

       self.root_dir = root_dir
       self.file = file
       self.year = year
       self.doy = doy

    # classes of different methods that
    # require these attributes from diagnostics.__init__

     class io:
        def loadfile()
         # loads the file from diagnostics.__init__.file
```

So I want to be able to do something like:

```
diag = diagnostics('.', 'file01.txt', '2007', '001')
diag.io.loadfile() # will load the file
```

Answer (score 2):

`diagnostics.io` has nothing to do with `diagnostics` other than existing in its namespace, and it certainly has nothing to do with any of its instances. Rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: What @James is doing almost looks like the RequireJS idiom.

Comment: So i take it it's not possible? And so instead i'd have to declare them as global or redefine them every time instead of encapsulating them?

Comment: If the values are static, it doesn't make sense to store them in a class instance.  Just use class attributes.  Also, you can stick the attributes directly on your `io` class.